# Alterar um atributo de uma classe base pela classe derivada C++

Tags: c++, classes, herança

Estou com um problema envolvendo herança em C++, não consigo alterar um atributo de uma classe base ex:

```
// classe base
class Base
{
    vector(string) Names; //coloquei entre parenteses porque por algum motivo o string desaparece quando coloco da maneira correta
    public:
        void Add(string);
        string Get(int);
};
void Base::Add(string name)
{
    this->Names.push_back(name);
}
string Base::Get(int name_position)
{
    return this->Names[name_position];
}
// classe derivada
class void Derived : public Base
{
    public:
        void New(string);
};
void Derived::New(string name)
{
    Base::Add(name);
}
```

O que estou fazendo no main é assim

```
  
Base base;
Derived derived;
derived.New("joao");
```

```
cout<<base.Get(0);
```

Alguém pode me dizer o que estou fazendo de errado, eu pensava que era possível alterar o atributo de uma classe base usando os métodos da própria classe base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tem alguns erros no seu código:

- `vector(string) Names;` deve ficar `vector<string> Names;`.

  Para que funcione tem que importar as respetivas bibliotecas:

  ```
  #include <vector>
  #include <string>
  ```

  E colocar o `using namespace std` ou transformar cada um em `std::vector` e `std::string`
- `class void Derived : public Base` ficou com a palavra reservada `void` a mais e deve passar a ser:

  ```
  class Derived : public Base
  ```
- `cout<<base.Get(0);` o que queria fazer na verdade era `cout<<derived.get(0)`. Repare que no seu main criou duas instancias:

  ```
  Base base;
  Derived derived;
  ```

  E depois atribui o nome através da instancia chamada `derived`:

  ```
  derived.New("joao");
  ```

  Esta instacia é do tipo `Derived` que deriva de `Base` e por isso tem o `vector<Names>` herdado. É nesta instancia que tem que utilizar o método `Get` que vai ao vetor herdado buscar o nome:

  ```
  cout<<derived.Get(0);
  ```

O seu código completo com essas correções seria:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Base{
    std::vector<std::string> Names;
    public:
        void Add(std::string);
        std::string Get(int);
};
void Base::Add(std::string name){
    this->Names.push_back(name);
}
std::string Base::Get(int name_position){
    return this->Names[name_position];
}
// classe derivada
class Derived : public Base{
    public:
        void New(std::string);
};
void Derived::New(std::string name){
    Base::Add(name);
}

int main(){
    Derived derived;
    derived.New("joao");
    std::cout<<derived.Get(0);

    return 0;
}
```

[Veja no Ideone como apresenta o resultado correto](https://ideone.com/MBdfwI)

Comment: No vector<string> Names eu tinha colocado entre parenteses porque o editor do stackoverflow estava apagando a palavra <string>. No class void Derived : public Base foi um erro de digitação e nao incluir as bibliotecas pois coloquei somente o trecho do exemplo. Mas ainda não era  o que eu queria, eu queria saber se não é possível chamar o método get da base e ele me retornar o valor, talvez eu esteja meio confuso com o uso de herança, vou estudar mais.

Comment: @gamedoido O exemplo que tinha são 2 objetos diferentes. Não pode colocar o valor num objeto e tentar obtê-lo noutro. A ideia da herança é que um objeto tem os campos e métodos da classe base e os campos e métodos da classe derivada. Ainda assim é tudo referente ao mesmo objeto. Nesses casos é comum de ter métodos da classe derivada que acedem a métodos/campos da classe base (referente ao mesmo objeto), tal como tem no seu exemplo. O valor que obtem em `derived.Get(0)` vem na verdade da classe `Base` pois é nela que foi definido o vetor de nomes

Comment: Entendi, obrigado @isac

Comment: @gamedoido Sem problema. Fico contente que tenha feito sentido.